# C file cannot be compiled in c++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, clr

For some reason I can no longer compile a c file in my c++ clr console application. It worked before without the clr support, I also switched my project to compile as /TP still not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'int strcmp(const char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'const char *'
```

## snowkill.c

```
#include "snowkill.h"

void killProcessByName(WCHAR *filename)
{
    HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof(pEntry);
    BOOL hRes = Process32First(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    while (hRes)
    {
        if (strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)
        {
            HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0,
                (DWORD)pEntry.th32ProcessID);
            if (hProcess != NULL && pEntry.th32ProcessID != GetCurrentProcessId())
            {
                TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
        hRes = Process32Next(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
}
```

## snowkill.h

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void killProcessByName(WCHAR *filename);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

## main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "snowkill.h"
#include "motion.h"
#include "info.h"
#include "flushsound.h"
#include "snowserial.h"

using namespace System;


bool on() {
    return true;
}

bool off() {
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    listenoncommport();
    for (;;) {
        string onoff = checkfile();

        if (onoff == "1")
        {
            //detected();
        }
        else
        {

            WCHAR *proccc = L"firefox.exe";
            killProcessByName(proccc);

            //notdetected();

        }
        Sleep(5000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong. `strcmp` takes a `char *`,  you are giving it a `wchar_t *`. You probably want [`wcscmp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx) which is basically the same as `strcmp` except it works on `wchar_t *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change every instance of WCHAR to TCHAR so text setting is "generic", or as already mentioned, change the project property character set to be Unicode only.

```
    void killProcessByName(TCHAR *filename)
    /* ... */
    if (_tcscmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)  /* replaced strcmp */
    /* ... */
#include <windows.h>    /* needed in order to use TEXT() macro */
    /* ... */
    TCHAR *proccc = TEXT("firefox.exe");   /* TEXT() is a <windows.h> macro */
```

Use TCHAR type everywhere if the functions involved are not WCHAR specific. That would allow project setting to build either ANSI/ASCII (not set) or Unicode.

Note that Process32First and Process32Next use TCHAR.

This is mostly for legacy, since Windows 2000 and later API functions use Unicode internally, converting ANSI/ASCII to Unicode as needed, while Windows NT and older API functions use ANSI/ASCII.

However, typically many or most text files (such as source code) are ANSI/ASCII and not Unicode, and it's awkward to have to support Unicode for Windows API and then ANSI/ASCII for text files in the same program, and for those projects I use ANSI/ASCII.

By using the TCHAR based generic types, I can share common code with projects that use Unicode and with projects that use ANSI/ASCII.

Comment: You mean ANSI, not ASCII. ANSI means the character encoding of the thread, which could come from the program, or the user, or the OS. It's very unlikely to be ASCII.

Comment: @TomBlodget - I updated my answer to show both. Take a look at [MSDN ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx3yt8af.aspx) .

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear: you have an error at this precise line:

```
if (strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)
```

Because your arguments are not of `char*` type as expected by [strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) but `WCHAR*` types. You should use [wcscmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wcscmp) instead, which is basically the same function, but working with `wchar_t*` type.

Answer (score 0):

`szExeFile` in `tagPROCESSENTRY32` is declared as `TCHAR`, which will be a 1-byte char when compiling with **Character Set** set to 'Not Set' or 'Multibyte'. Set Character Set in your project settings to **Use Unicode Character Set** to fix the problem.

Also, use `wcscmp` to compare WCHAR types.